# How can I make OSX to upload files to icloud?

Tags: icloud, mojave

As you can see from the screenshot, some of the files have the 'download from icloud' icon to the right of the file name, but some of them (from DSCF6758.RAF onwards) are not.

[image: Folder]

The folder is on the iCloud Drive.

I still have plenty of space in the iCloud.

At the moment my SSD drive is low on free space (only 5% free space left)

[image: iTerm df outcome]

How can I trigger the upload process on these not-yet-uploaded files?

Comment: Also - those files should already be in the cloud - you just want them purged from local storage - not uploaded. Do you suspect they’re not uploaded and Finder is incorrect in showing that they are synced?

Comment: You're right. It is just my expectation that the cloud icon should appear straight away. I have since logged in to icloud.com and verified the files were uploaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menubar app Bailiff lets your pin files on your drive and evict them without needing to wait for the background processes to do the work for you.

- https://eclecticlight.co/cirrus-bailiff/

Once you’ve got the files removed, you still need to wait for snapshots to purge. The `df` command isn’t going to show you purgeable content, so this tool. It might not be sufficient to fix what you’re trying to do in the end, but it does do what you asked.